# How do I reorder or auto-increment the primary key of a table if it is not being incremented properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I inherited a SQL Server database and for some reason the primary key is not being incremented properly.

For example, the PK for the last record in the table is 120350

Then, when I enter a new record into the table, it gets the PK 48377

What would be the best way to reorder or set the initial PK for new records? This is for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You can reseed your identity. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx I would be extremely worried about an identity that is suddenly was less than the max values. This is an indication that either a reseed has happened before OR some data was created with identity_insert on. You need to figure out what happened there and why.

Comment: Yeah, I just have no idea where to even look. This table is used to post back shipping data from our USPS and UPS programs. It _should_ just be writing to the next incremental row.

Comment: There will be gaps depending on the version of sql server. With 2008+ there is a documented behavior that there will be gaps after a server restart. However, the values should not be less than existing rows assuming your step setting on the identity property is positive.

Comment: @SeanLange How do I check the step setting? Do you mean the Identity Increment? If so, that is just set to 1.

Comment: Yes the increment. Not sure you will be able to figure out what happened in the past. I would say you could just reseed it a value higher than the current largest value. Assuming there is nothing else changing things in there you should be fine.

Comment: @SeanLange That's what I was thinking. `DBCC CHECKIDENT (',<table name>', RESEED, <current column value>)` right?

Comment: Yes that would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('<tablename>');
```

This will reseed the identity column to where it should be (in this case 120351). If you want to reorder the existing value then you'll need to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT '<tablename>' ON` as part of a script to move the rows around. How you do that depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Keep in mind that you'll also need to keep any foreign keys in sync.

If you have some other requirements on the column that defines, "incremented properly" then you might need something besides an `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: You can't "move rows around". An identity column is not updateable even when IDENTITY_INSERT is on. To "change" those values requires a delete and an insert with the new value.

Comment: When I use `DBCC CHECKIDENT('UPS_Worldship_Export');` this is the result: Checking identity information: current identity value '48377', current column value '120351'. Adding a new row still just gets set as 48377. Any ideas?

Comment: A delete and an insert... hence, "move those rows around".

Comment: @JustinHollender How are you inserting the rows?

Comment: @TomH The UPS and USPS programs write to this table

Comment: @TomH Should I just reseed the value? `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('UPS_Worldship_Export', RESEED, 120351)`

Comment: I have no idea what the "UPS" and "USPS" programs are or how they are writing to your table. I would try explicitly reseeding the value and if that doesn't work then I would suspect that the USP/USPS programs are using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` to override the `IDENTITY` column and you'll have to find a way around that. You could also try rebuilding the indexed and then rerunning the `DBCC` command, but I doubt that would do much'

Answer (score 0):

When I use

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('UPS_Worldship_Export');
```

I got this result: *Checking identity information: current identity value '48377', current column value '120351'.*

Somehow, the value was offtrack. Thanks to the comments above, I just reseeded the value to the highest value and it works correctly now.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (',<table name>', RESEED, <current column value>);
```